# ¿Hay alguna manera de acceder a la información de build.gradle desde el código con DART en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

Buenas a todo el mundo.
¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo acceder a la info que hay en el fichero de buil.gradle desde el código?
Necesito usar esa info y obtenerla en una variable, pero siy incapaz de encontrar la forma y tampoco encuentro nada específico en internet.
Sería de mucha ayuda si pudiérais ayudarme. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas acceder al build gradle?

Comment: Bienvenida, recuerda agregar a tus preguntas lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor revisa [ask], si deseas opiniones puedes obtener reputación para realizar este tipo de preguntas en [chat], saludos.